# Type parameters defining each other? class A<T1, T2> where T1 : Foo where T2 : T1

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance, variance

Does

```
class A<T1, T2>
    where T1 : Foo
    where T2 : T1
```

have an actual use case?

What's the difference to

```
class A<T1, T2>
    where T1 : Foo
    where T2 : Foo
```

? What does actually change?

Is it the same when variance is involved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is that `T2` cannot be just any `Foo` it has to be a `Foo` that is derived from `T1`.

For instance

```
public class Foo{}
public class Foo1 : Foo {}
public class Foo2 : Foo {}
public class Foo12 : Foo1 {}
public class A<T1,T2> where T1: Foo where T2 : T1 {}
```

will allow

```
var a = new A<Foo1, Foo12>()
```

but not

```
var a  = new A<Foo1, Foo2>()
```

This also means that you can safely cast an object of type `T2` to `T1`.

> Is it the same when variance is involved?

Variance only comes into play with interfaces.